# Reditect url from the method of notify_url of paypal in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

i am using paypal for payment. in paypal i found two type url -

1. return_url
2. notify_url

i wan to check the validity after transaction, save some data and then redirect buyer to receipt page with a unique value that is saved in db. that is why i m not using redirect_url

here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TestPaypalIpn()
        {
            var response = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            string address = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&" + response;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Streamstech\Content\requestAddress.txt", address);

            try
            {
                string result = webClient.DownloadString(address);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Streamstech\Content\response.txt", result);
                if (result == "VERIFIED")
                {
                    if (Request.Params["payment_status"] == "Completed" && Request.Params["business"] == Request.Params["receiver_email"])
                    {
                        var lisenceKey = Request.Params["transaction_subject"];

                        var userProductLisence = UserProductLisenceRepository.GetConditional(
                        l => l.LisenceKey == lisenceKey).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (userProductLisence != null)
                        {
                            if (userProductLisence.PaypalTransactionId == null)
                            {
                                userProductLisence.PaypalTransactionId = Request.Params["txn_id"];
                                userProductLisence.PayerEmailForPaypalTransaction = Uri.EscapeUriString(Request.Params["payer_email"]);
                                UserProductLisenceRepository.Edit(userProductLisence);
                                return RedirectToAction("Receipt", "Transaction", new { requestId = userProductLisence.LisenceKey });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Transaction", new { errorname = "", errorMessage = "something went wrong, try again later" });
                }
                return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Transaction", new { errorname = "verification Problem", errorMessage = "Transaction not verified" });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Streamstech\Content\error.txt", e.Message);
                return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Transaction", new { errorname = "Error..!!!", errorMessage = "something went wrong, try again later" });
                throw;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

here i can compare, save data to database.. but it is not redirecting to receipt page.. what is the problem here in code...??

or any suggestion how can i do it.. ?
Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to use return_url instead of notify_url. For notify_url, it's used for receiving message in system back end and you maybe can't receive it immediately after payment is done. refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/